# controls in ModalPopupExtender not firing

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a ModalPopupExtender extending a panel and in the panel, there is a function i want to perform which is executed with a button within the panel and after it executes, it will close the panel.

However,btnProcess when click is not firing btnProcess_Click at all.. debugging shows that the function is not executed at all

I am clueless of why it's not firing.

```
         <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Height="600px" Width="800px" CssClass="ModalWindow">

                <asp:Button ID="btnProcess" runat="server" Text="Ok" onclick="btnProcess_Click"/>

            </asp:Panel>
            <ajaxToolkit:RoundedCornersExtender ID="Panel1_RoundedCornersExtender" runat="server"
                Enabled="True" TargetControlID="Panel1" Radius="10" BorderColor="Black">
            </ajaxToolkit:RoundedCornersExtender>
            <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="Panel1_ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" DynamicServicePath=""
                BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" Enabled="True" PopupControlID="Panel1" TargetControlID="dummy" >
            </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
```

this is the code it supposed to run.

```
 protected void btnProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     //process .. bla bla bla
    Panel1_ModalPopupExtender.hide();
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and I solved it by add this line to your code behind:

```
 btnProcess.OnClientClick = String.Format("fnClickDoPostBack('{0}','{1}')", btnOk.UniqueID, "");
```

and this in your markup :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function fnClickDoPostBack(sender, e) {
                __doPostBack(sender, e);
            }
        </script>
```